# Get several buttons' ID with single method

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm building a program with C# in Windows Forms, and the following question came to me. I have several buttons in my form and when any of them is clicked, I want to be able to store its ID in a single variable that will handle only one ID at a time. I already have a method that does this, but the fact is I don't want to call this method from the event handler of each button:

```
button1_Click(object senders /* ... yada yada ... */)
```

Is there a way how I can simplify this with a single method? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need many `Click` event handlers for your buttons, just 1 is enough:

```
private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   Button button = sender as Button;
   //do something with the clicked button
   //...
}
```

Comment: thx ive already put ur suggestion to use and it works perfectly, i prety much apreciate your help, thx a lot